# How to save an array of Items in AsyncStorage React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What i want to make is a bookmark list, but i don't know how i can save an array of items in AsyncStorage, my skills are basic on react.

I just need the function to save posts (post image, title and id) when i press the button "Save to bookmark".

```
export default class PostDetails extends Component {

constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   const {params} = props.navigation.state;
   this.state = {
     item: params.item
   };
}

render() {

   const {item} = this.state;  

   return (

   <Image source={{uri: item.post_image}}/>

   <Text> {item.post_id} </Text>
   <Text> {item.post_title} </Text>

   <Button>
      <Text> Save to Bookmark </Text>
   </Button>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use `JSON.stringify(arrayToSave)`; see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for `JSON.stringify()`. It will convert the array to a JSON string that can be saved to `AsyncStorage` and then can be retrieved at a later stage.

```
const saveBookmarks = async (bookmarksArray) => {
  try {
    const bookmarksString = JSON.stringify(bookmarksArray);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MyStore:bookmarks',bookmarksString);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};

<Button onClick={() => saveBookmarks(yourArray)} />
```

To retrieve it you can use `const theSavedArray = JSON.parse(stringFromAsyncStorage)`; the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for `JSON.parse()`

```
try {
  const bookmarksString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyStore:bookmarks');
  if (bookmarksString !== null){
    // We have data!!
    const bookmarksArray = JSON.parse(bookmarksString);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

Comment: you don't have an example please?

Comment: but how i can include the posts details in the first function? sorry never i use the asyncstorage

Comment: It is not clear from the question where your array comes from so I have just placeholders in there

Comment: ok i resolve it, how i can get the bookmark list in FlatList component?

Comment: I think that is a separate question @bdroid

Comment: i can't post a new question, i need to wait 90 minutes

Comment: in any case your answer is not complete :/

Comment: What's not complete? your question only asks how to save items to asyncStorage, @Tony 's answers shows how to save & retrieve them.